# Correct PSI for aftermarket tires on aftermarket wheels?

Tags: tires, mercedes-benz

I drive a 2017 Mercedes GLC 43 AMG.  After replacing the original tires (staggered) with new wheels and tires of a different size, I have been unable to get an answer to the question of the correct PSI to inflate them to. Neither Goodyear, Mercedes, TireRack (the retailer) or Firestone (the installer) could provide an answer.  The old / new details are below.  Any thoughts?

original tires were:

255/40 ZR 21 (FRONT) - 35 PSI recommended
285/35 ZR 21 (REAR) - 38 PSI recommended

I replaced all 4 wheels / tires with 20x9 wheels and

255/45 R 20 GOODYEAR EAGLE SPORT RUNFLAT.

If it helps GAWR is as follows:

2668 FRONT, 2822 REAR.

Answer (score 2):

I would try 35psi all round then look at the tires to see how they sit before driving, and then drive it to feel how it handles.